# jQueryUI Slider - Getting the initial slider values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I implemented the jQueryUI slider and want to display the min & max slider values in 2 different divs. The values in the div will update as the user adjusts the slider. The divs will also show the initial values of the slider.

**Problem:** The div shows `[object object]` as the intial values, but shows the correct updated values as the slider is adjusted by the user. I need some help to get the initial values displayed.

**jQuery Code:**

```
$("#filter_submenu_rent").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#rent_min" ).html( "Min: $" + ui.values[ 0 ] );
        $( "#rent_max" ).html( "Max: $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }
})
$( "#rent_min" ).html( "Min: $" + $( "#slider_rent" ).slider( "values", 0 ));
$( "#rent_max" ).html( "Max: $" + $( "#slider_rent" ).slider( "values", 1 ));
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="filter_submenu_rent">
            <div id="rent_min"></div>
            <div id="slider_rent"></div>
            <div id="rent_max"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code (Another Attempt)**
*Nothing appears in the 2 divs initially when this is used*

```
$("#filter_submenu_rent").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#rent_min" ).html( "Min: $" + ui.values[ 0 ] );
        $( "#rent_max" ).html( "Max: $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $( "#rent_min" ).html( "Min: $" + ui.values[ 0 ] );
        $( "#rent_max" ).html( "Max: $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue i see is that you have two different objects as your slider:

the definition is `$("#filter_submenu_rent").slider` but the code later is: `$( "#slider_rent" ).slider`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4tDjZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Some may find this a bit hacky, but I've found that you can put custom properties into the slider options object and access them like any other slider option later.

```
$('#myslider').slider({min: 0, max: 10, value: 5, myinitval: 5});

// will remain 5, unless your event handlers change it
$('#myslider').slider('option', 'myinitval');
```